# How to call a member through its parent's type that shadowed a parent class implementation

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

This is a challenging one that got me stumped while I was coding today. Suppose I am running the `Sub Test1()` and `Test2()` and would like to print out the value of the `Shadows` method of the *instance* of the object I am passing in to `TestCall()` (see below - it is clearer) using the following restrictions:

1. Can't change the contents of `Class A`, `B`, and `C`
2. Can't change `Sub Test1()` and `Sub Test2()`
3. TestCall() can't have an `if`, `select case` etc. statement that tries to figure out the type of the argument passed in and then do `CType(o, <C or B>).Method()`. Suppose there are an infinite number of classes like `B` and `C` all of which inherit from `A` or `B` or `C` and shadow `Method`
4. You can't change the attributes of Subs (i.e. you can't change `Shadows` to `Overridable/Overrides`)

I would like to dynamically do the equivalent of `CType(o, C).Method()` and print out `C.Method` for Test1 and then dynamically do the equivalent of `CType(o, B).Method()` and print out `B.Method`.

```
<TestFixture()> _
Public Class Test

    <Test()>
    Public Sub Test1()
        Dim o As A = New C
        TestCall(o)  '<-- THIS SHOULD PRINT "C.Method"
    End Sub

    Public Sub Test2()
        Dim o As A = New B
        TestCall(o)  '<-- THIS SHOULD PRINT "B.Method"
    End Sub

    Public Sub TestCall(ByVal o as A)
          o.Method() 
    End Sub

    Class A
        Public Sub Method()
            Console.WriteLine("A.Method")
        End Sub
    End Class

    Class B
        Inherits A

        Public Shadows Sub Method()
            Console.WriteLine("B.Method")
        End Sub
    End Class

    Class C
        Inherits B

        Public Shadows Sub Method()
            Console.WriteLine("C.Method")
        End Sub
    End Class
End Class
```

Comment: In essence you are asking: how to call a shadowing method as if it is the overriding method, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to do this as I discovered a few days ago WITHOUT reflection:

```
Public Sub TestCall(ByVal someAorBorC as A)
    Convert.ChangeType(someAorBorC, someAorBorC.GetType()).Method()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You problem comes from the fact that if you use the keyword `Shadows` you create a new method with the same name that hides the original method, the inverse of overriding an overridable (virtual) method.

The only way that I can think of to solve this dynamically is to find out the declaring type, query that type for existing methods of a certain signature and then call that method.

If this is what you are after, the following code for TestCall (sorry, in C#, but you tagged your question with C#) will do. The only thing you need to know is the name of the method, which you had to know in the original situation also.

```
public void TestCall(A someAorBorC)
{
    // store declaring type
    Type T = someAorBorC.GetType();

    // find shadowed method
    var method = (from m in T.GetMethods()
                 where m.DeclaringType == T
                 && m.Name == "Method"
                 select m).SingleOrDefault();
    if (method == null)
        throw new Exception("Method 'Method' not found in declaring type");

    // call method
    method.Invoke(someAorBorC, null);
}

// Console:
C.Method
B.Method
```

Comment: Not worries about C#. Don't care what .NET language you favor. We noticed a more complicated version of this problem in a third-party software that we bought that had this "Shadows" for almost every sub instead of "Virtual/Overrides" (can't replace - TOO MANY PLACES)and we found a bug in it so were thinking of a good way to fix it. (my test example essentially tries to capture the problem in a very simple scenario) Reflection is good and I briefly thought about it and would be my last resort but I was thinking maybe there is some other trick here that I don't know about...

Comment: @Denis: no, there's no other trick (other than different reflection approaches). However, if you need to use this in other scenario's then tests (OP), then I suggest you cache the method. The lookup is very expensive.